# Ordered intent between two apps

Tags: android

I want to implement ordered intent between two applications(sendOrderedBroadcast ). I have unsuccessfully tried it, the intent is only taken by receiver in intent sending app and not by receivers of second app. Can anyone provide some useful links or code as I haven't been able to find it over net.

Activity sending ordered intent (APP 1)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


                Intent in = new Intent("com.example.mnit.ordered");
                in.putExtra("data", "hello");
                sendOrderedBroadcast(in, null);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Manifest of APP-2

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mnit.orderedpair">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver android:name="com.example.mnit.orderedpair.Receiver1">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1">
                <action android:name="com.example.mnit.ordered" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.mnit.orderedpair.Receiver3">
            <intent-filter android:priority="3">
                <action android:name="com.example.mnit.ordered" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Recevier1 of APP-2

```
public class Receiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String res = getResultData();
        try {

            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/dir1");
            dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir, "calllogs.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(res.getBytes());
            fos.close();

        }        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        Toast.makeText(context, "RCVR 1.." + res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Receiver2 of APP-2

```
public class Receiver3 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s = intent.getExtras().getString("data");
        Toast.makeText(context, "RCVR 3.." + s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setResultData(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is an ordered intent?

Comment: Did you mean Content Provider?

Comment: sending intent with priority given to broadcast receivers

Comment: No not content provider @OnkarNene

Comment: Show your code, then people can help.  Ordered broadcasts have been in since API level 1 and are used within the system, they definitely work.

Comment: In app 1, try calling through to the superclass first, then send the broadcast. The call to the superclass `onCreate()` handles some internal setup of the `Activity` and `Context`, so this could be causing you problems.